# How to create a person-specific (personalized) classification model using machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have labeled datasets for 10 subjects that contain photoplethysmogram (PPG) signal value and the affective state as a label.

How can I create a person-specific(Personalized) classification model to classify the subject affective state?

Do I need to merge all 10 datasets in one dataset and train the model? or shall I create a separate model for each subject by using his data (this may not help in classifying the affective state of unseen persons? 
?

Comment: do you want to predict the person or the affective state? What is y and X?

Comment: predict affective state, X: PPG values,  and y: Affective state (Mediation, Baseline..etc)

Comment: I guess pooling the data and adding an indicator per subject is the thing to do. By doing so, you have good variation in the data, plus sufficient observations, while the subject indicator - like „fixed effect“ - controls for aspects related to each subject. I would first try with a logistic model, possibly with regulation, and then see where to go further. Happy coding!